# Web Scrapping with a 'for' cycle in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, web-scraping

Im trying to do a web scraping to fill a new variable in a dataset. But after 53 iterations, it blocks the code and i cant run it again. I cant run the loop code and it also blocks when i try to run it with a single value.

My code is

```
with open('unique_links.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        url=line
        cache_URL = "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search"

        def get_data(link):
            hdr = {
                "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Mobile Safari/537.36"
            }
            params = {
                'q': 'cache:' + link
            }
            req = requests.get(cache_URL, headers=hdr, params=params)
            return req.text


        soup = BeautifulSoup(get_data(url), 'html.parser')
        print(soup.select_one('.table-big-value-birthday').text)
        df_clean['BornDate'] = soup.select_one('.table-big-value-birthday').text
```

I have a database with the values of the players link in a column. The .txt file has the unique values of that database.

Some of the links on the .txt are:
`https://www.atptour.com/en/players/novak-djokovic/d643/overview https://www.atptour.com/en/players/daniil-medvedev/mm58/overview https://www.atptour.com/en/players/rafael-nadal/n409/overview https://www.atptour.com/en/players/alexander-zverev/z355/overview`

After the code returns an AtributeError, I print the 'soup' and I can see the message:
"Our systems have detected unusual traffic from your computer network."(...)"This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the [Terms of Service](//www.google.com/policies/terms/)."
How can I fix this block, and also, how can I create a way around this in order to get the values that I need for my 1662 links.

(Sorry if it was confusing, I cant explaint in verry well)

Answer (score 0):

Don't spam websites with traffic. You need to properly [ratelimit](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/) your requests or you will be timed out or even banned.

Comment: That was what was happening.Oh okay, so in my example, should i put this before my code in order to work?
from ratelimit import limits

import requests

FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 900

@limits(calls=15, period=FIFTEEN_MINUTES)